# Click on a button using Selenium and scrapy spider

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I just started and I've been on this for a week or two. Just using the internet to help but now I reached the point where I cant understand or my problem cannot be found anywhere else. In case you didnt understand my program I want to scrape data then click on a button then scrape data until I scrape an already collected data. then go to the next page which is in the list.
I reached the point where I scrape the first 8 data but I cant find a way to click on the "see more!" button. I know I should use Selenium and the button's Xpath. Anyway here is my code :

```
class KickstarterSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'kickstarter'
allowed_domains = ['kickstarter.com']
start_urls = ["https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/zwim/zwim-smart-swimming-goggles/community", "https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/zunik/oriboard-the-amazing-origami-multifunctional-cutti/community"]

def _init_(self, driver):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

def parse(self, response):
    self.driver.get('https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/zwim/zwim-smart-swimming-goggles/community')
    backers = response.css('.founding-backer.community-block-content')
    b = backers[0]

    while True:
        try:
            seemore = selfdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content-wrap"]').click()
        except:
            break
    self.driver.close()

def parse2(self,response):
    print('you are here!')


    for b in backers:
        name = b.css('.name.js-founding-backer-name::text').extract_first()
        backed = b.css('.backing-count.js-founding-backer-backings::text').extract_first()
        print(name, backed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Be shure web driver used in scrapy loads and interprets JS (idk... it can be a solution)